# Failed to build tensorflow iOS binaries with selective registration

Tags: ios, tensorflow

I am a new user of tensorflow. I wish to integrate a specific graph.pb file into an ios device, and have followed all the compilation instructions carefully as described in [tensorflow git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile).

yet when I try to run the camera example app I get the error:

```
 E /tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/ios/camera_copy/tensorflow_utils.mm:140] Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv2D' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

         [[{{node pyramid_regression_0/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](input_2, pyramid_regression_0/kernel/read)]]
    2018-08-22 16:54:00.303760: F tensorflow/examples/ios/camera_copy/tensorflowUtil.mm:68] Couldn't load model: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Conv2D' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[{{node pyramid_regression_0/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](input_2, pyramid_regression_0/kernel/read)]]
```

I also followed the instructions according to the solution offered in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9073), but I got there are some differences (probably due to the versions diffs between a year ago and now (Aug 2018))

1. `bazel build --copt="-DUSE_GEMM_FOR_CONV" tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header` compiled without errors
2. then created the `ops_to_register.h` file:

   - when used the *bazel-bin* command, it adds a strange print of `tf.estimator package not installed` to the first line. 
     In addition, during the file creation this warning appears multiple times:
     `RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88`
   - when I create the `ops_to_register.h` file using *python3* , it creates the file without strange prints

   in both cases there are no occurrences of **strcmp** or **strcmpc** at all, and got `Conv2DUsingGemmOp` op in the *bazel* created file instead of `Conv2DOp` by *python3*
3. I tried to use the `ops_to_register.h` file for the `tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_ios_tensorflow.sh` compilation, but it fails during the compilation:

   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
     "nsync::nsync_cv_signal(nsync::nsync_cv_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::notify_one() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_cv_wait_with_deadline(nsync::nsync_cv_s_*, nsync::nsync_mu_s_*, timespec, nsync::nsync_note_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::wait_until_system_clock(tensorflow::mutex_lock&, std::__1::chrono::time_point > >) in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_cv_init(nsync::nsync_cv_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::condition_variable() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_from_time_point_(std::__1::chrono::time_point > >)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::wait_until_system_clock(tensorflow::mutex_lock&, std::__1::chrono::time_point > >) in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_cv_wait(nsync::nsync_cv_s_*, nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::wait(tensorflow::mutex_lock&) in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_mu_runlock(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::mutex::unlock_shared() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_mu_rlock(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::mutex::lock_shared() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_mu_unlock(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::mutex::unlock() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_mu_lock(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::mutex::lock() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_cv_broadcast(nsync::nsync_cv_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::condition_variable::notify_all() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
     "nsync::nsync_mu_init(nsync::nsync_mu_s_*)", referenced from:
         tensorflow::mutex::mutex() in libtensorflow-core-arm64.a(mutex.o)
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

   make: 
   [/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/ios_ARM64/benchmark] Error 1

   '[' 2 -ne 0 ']'

   echo 'arm64 compilation failed.'

   arm64 compilation failed.

   exit 1

**environment details:**

- tensorflow 1.9.0 (there is tensorflow 1.10.0, but is currently not supported for the ios compilations)
- python 3.6.6
- all the compilations are done with -a arm64 only

does anyone have an idea what went wrong here?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar error when compiling for the raspberry pi, I had to manually export the environment variables HOST_NSYNC_LIB and TARGET_NSYNC_LIB

First check if you have them already exported: echo $HOST_NSYNC_LIB

if that is empty you should look where your nsync library is compiled (just look for libnsync.a)
Then export both paths:

```
export HOST_NSYNC_LIB='your/path/to/libnsync.a'
export TARGET_NSYNC_LIB="$HOST_NSYNC_LIB"
```

Hope this works for you!